# TypeError: cannot serialize None (type NoneType) in ElementTree alternative to if statements

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, elementtree

I can't find a practical solution in the documentation of ElementTree module for avoiding getting "TypeError: cannot serialize None (type NoneType)" when I try to set an attribute to None. Like here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
myvar = None
p = ET.Element('test')
b = ET.SubElement(p, 'tt')
b.set("last_update",myvar)
tree = ET.ElementTree(p)
tree.write('test.xml')
```

I know that I could use a series of `if myvar is not None: ...` but I would have to repeat the if statement many times. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid writing the attribute at all if the value of the attribute is None.

Comment: Why don't you use `myvar = "None"`? Attribute values are strings.

Comment: @mzjn in my case I don't want None to appear in the xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a subroutine to remove all `None` attributes from a tree. Just call this function before any serialization.

```py
def removeNoneAttrib(elem):
    """Remove None attributes from XML tree"""
    elem.attrib = {
        k: elem.attrib[k]
        for k in elem.attrib
        if elem.attrib[k] is not None
    }
    for subelem in elem:
        removeNoneAttrib(subelem)
```

Example:

```
# ... the same as your code until the last line
removeNoneAttrib(tree.getroot())
tree.write('test.xml')
```

Note: If you had any check of the form `elem.attrib[x] is None` replace it with `x not in elem.attrib`.